# Read files in blocks with MASM

Tags: file, io, masm

I want to read a file by blocks with MASM. The Win32 documentation says that I have to add an OVERLAPPED structure, but I don't know how to make that structure in memory.

Does reserving the corresponding sizes of the elements of the structure work?

Which are the sizes of union and struct?

Can you suggest me another way to do it?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OVERLAPPED stuctures are used by Windows API functions for asynchronous functions, which return immediately prior to its calling to allow other functions to access the OVERLAPPED structure. There is no size for the UNION and STRUCT directives because it is only an indicator to the assembler (or in most cases, the programmer) that a certain block of data is either a UNION or a structure. When you specify a UNION in MASM, you can use the variable associated with the UNION directive to represent the various elements of the block (db, dw, dd, etc.) as a single element (however, is only true in practice, because in assembly, you can bypass this by simply accessing the individual elements of the block of data).  A STRUCT, on the other hand, has a separate memory location for each of its elements and they all can be used at once.

Lastly, because the OVERLAPPED operator does not exist in MASM, I suggest using STRUCT as so:

```
mystruct    struct
db          byteelement
dd          doublewordelement
mystruct    ends
```

Of course, you should change this code to match the OVERLAPPED structure for your function according to your needs.

You can find more information on MASM directives here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t163bt0.aspx

Hope this helps.